# What to do when the FirebaseAuth is loading when you want to use a Bool provider to manage Auth State

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-go-router

I have a simple Riverpod Provider(bool) that watches another Provider(which returns auth state changes) and I want to use I to control wether a user is signed in or not (true of false), this is my attempt so far but it comes with the problem that when I try to use it with GoRouter redirection it keeps trying to reroute because Loading turns false, what should I do to make this work with my GoRoute redirection, I can't have loading be true of false but I also only have true or false to work with:

The Stream provider returning FirebaseAuthState changes:

```
@riverpod
class UserAuth extends _$UserAuth {
  @override
  Stream<User?> build() {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
  }
}
```

The provider in control of whether a user is signed in or not:

```
@riverpod
class AuthState extends _$AuthState {
  @override
  bool build() {
    final authuser = ref.watch(userAuthProvider);

    return authuser.when(
      data: (userData) {
        return true;
      },
      loading: () {
        return false;
      }, // Replace with your loading widget
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        return false;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And my redirecting found in a GoRouter Provider:

```
redirect: (context, state) {
  bool authState = ref.watch(authStateProvider);
  print(authState);
  if (authState == true) {
    return '/';
  } else {
    return '/welcomepage';
  }
},
```

my problem is my app keeps trying to redirect over and over again when I first run it and I think its because im returning my loading as true but im not sure.

Comment: You have answered your own question in describing the problem. A boolean provider is not suitable for this purpose in GoRouter because it does not consider the "loading" state. You should instead use your FirebaseAuthState stream provider directly in GoRouter.

Comment: That's what I was wanting to do but could never find a way to do it

Comment: the problem would be if I use authuser.when(). I will have to choose between homepage, loading-age,errorpage. I would have no way to differentiate between needing to go to login page and homepage